# resize and cache remote images using php and store the original and the duplicate

Tags: php, image, jpeg, gif

I want to get remote images and resize them and store them as well as storing the original images.

I would like an option to regenerate images /thumbnails as well, so they are updated automatically.

The types of images that should be allowed are gif and jpeg

If possible then gif should also be converted to jpeg.

Anyone has simple class or function to do this?

Comment: You really should start using Google and reading manuals. Seven closed questions in just 3 weeks... that's a bit much, mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Get remote images**: [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) or (assuming `allow_url_fopen`) simply [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
2. **Resize Images**: [gd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)